# Difference in the maximum values of a Raster band when using numpy array and when using gdal function directly

Tags: python, raster, gdal, numpy, band

```
import numpy as np
from gdalconst import*
band = 'band1.tif'
band1_12 = dataset1_12.GetRasterBand(1)
max = band1_12.GetMaximum() 
print(max) #this gives 2425.0

data1 = np.array(band1_12.ReadAsArray()).astype(np.float)
data1 = data1.flatten()
max = np.amax(data1)
print(max) #this gives 1977.0
```

What is the possible cause of error?
Also if I use gdalinfo band1.tif , I see the max value as 2425

I am using gdal version- '1100100' and python 3 on Jupyter Notebook.

Link to file band1.tif -[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0XWIpFvBih3SlhTWjZwLUFaMXc)

Comment: What software are you using? GDAL? If so, please [edit] your question or at least the tags to clarify.

Comment: Yes GetMaximum() is a function of gdal library.

Comment: If you supply the version number of both `GDAL` and `python`, someone might point to a (previous) bug. Where did you download `GDAL` from or have you build it your self? If you supply the contents of `dataset1_12` or `band1_12` someone might try to replicate your test.

Comment: Chau I have added all the details, you asked.Thanks!

Comment: Your question remains quite unclear so I think you should review and edit it some more.  I *think* it may be that you are trying to understand why `band1_12.GetMaximum()` gives a different result to `np.amax(data1)` but from what I can see you have not provided a code snippet or snippets that a tester could just copy/paste to run your test.

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo , Yes you are right. I want to understand why I am getting two different values. I have done the editing. Thanks!